# Store date as unix timestamp or TIMESTAMP data type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design, timestamp

I need to store dates (with time) in a MySQL database. I want to be able to format these how I like. Then what is the best way to store dates in a MySQL database? The DATETIME type, the TIMESTAMP type or simply a unix timestamp in a numeric data type? I will be retrieving the dates using PHP.

Comment: int(11) > https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126015/2065594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Usually* it does not matter whether you use `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` datatype.

- In older versions, `TIMESTAMP` was 4 bytes and `DATETIME` was 8.
- Think of `DATETIME` as a picture of a clock; think of `TIMESTAMP` as an instant in time, worldwide.  That is, if you connect to the same database, but from a different timezone, a `DATETIME` will look the the same, but a `TIMESTAMP` will be adjusted for timezone.
- `NOW()`, `SELECTing` into PHP, etc, are compatible with both.
- Both are externally seen as a string, such as '2015-04-25 17:09:01'.
- Since `TIMESTAMP` is stored as a 32-bit integer (but you don't see that), it is limited to ~1970-2038.
- Since `DATETIME` is clock time, there will be a missing/extra hour twice a year if you switch to/from daylight savings time.

Yes, you could use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and have an `INT UNSIGNED`, but wouldn't it be better to see '2015-...'?  (That would be 4 bytes.)

Comment: Wouldn't unix timestamps be more useful if I wanted to format the time myself (instead of letting SQL do it, which is preformatted)?

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` gives you lots of options.  It works with `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` datatypes, without the need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

Comment: But is there a reason to nót use a unix time? Is it preferred to format inside SQL (with DATE_FORMAT()) rather than inside PHP (or any other language)? I'd say a unix timestamp is more generalized, as basically every language knows how to deal with those.

Comment: Sure, use unix time -- but do you prefer to store unix time in a `TIMESTAMP` field?  Or an `INT UNSIGNED` field (as a number)?  (I prefer `TIMESTAMP`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime type to store timestamp & insert current timestamp using now() in mysql or get dates/timestamps via any methods you find suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer storing it as long which is always from epoch and represent UTC. This helps when we have to cater to different localization and timezone aspect -other wise we would end up storing values in either DB server default or JVM default locale.