# How to store epoch timestamp in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, epoch

I have a table that needs to store epoch timestamp.

```
class CreateKlines < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :klines do |t|
      t.string :symbol
      t.timestamp :open_time
      t.timestamp :close_time

      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

However, when I stored it, it becomes `nil` 
(*the `open_time` and the `close_time`)

EX:

```
Kline.create(open_time: Time.now.to_i)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO `klines` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2020-05-14 01:45:22', '2020-05-14 01:45:22')
   (3.8ms)  COMMIT
```

You can notice that the value of `open_time` is gone, and the result is

```
#<Kline:0x00007f9f68c87788
 id: 600,
 symbol: nil,
 open_time: nil,
 close_time: nil,
 created_at: Thu, 14 May 2020 01:45:22 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 14 May 2020 01:45:22 UTC +00:00>
```

Env:

Rails 5.1.4, 
Ruby 2.6.5, 
MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Rails has two "special" timestamps, `created_at` and `updated_at` that Rails automatically stores and updates it properly (`t.timestamps` will generate those columns). Otherwise, it's not special meaning you need to set it manually.

So for example,

```rb
def open
  update(open_time: Time.current)
end
```

a method like this can do what you want, and you can add anything to this method so that it does other things besides updating a column.

Comment: While accurate, if you look at their example they're doing this already (through `create`, instead of `update`)

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why I can't do it right. Or should I switch to `int`?

Answer (score 0):

I realize my question wasn't related to Rails. I shouldn't use `timestamp` to store epoch time.

[What is the data type for unix_timestamp (MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125947/what-is-the-data-type-for-unix-timestamp-mysql)

Instead, I should use `int(11)` to store it.

Back to my question. If I want to store `timestamp`, I should use the `time` object in Rails.

EX:

```
Kline.create(open_time: Time.now)
(1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO `klines` (`open_time`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2020-05-14 01:49:15', '2020-05-14 01:49:15', '2020-05-14 01:49:15')
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
```