# Save integer timestamp to timestamp field in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0` and I am having in my migration the following field:

```
$table->timestamp('trx_timestamp', 0)->nullable($value = true);
```

Over my API I get the field the following way:

[image]

Currently, I am saving it plainly without converting it. However, this does result in `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values in my db.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And what do you get on dd?

Comment: Its better if you format your unix timestamp to date and save in database other wise you need to save it as `int(11)` [What is the data type for unix_timestamp (MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125947/what-is-the-data-type-for-unix-timestamp-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to save data (currently in timestamp) as a date time, convert it and save. you can do it like this.

```
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timeStamp)->format('M d Y');
```

Or

```
$date = Carbon::parse($timeStamp)->format('M d Y');
```

Check the carbon package, it is very useful when working with date times.

Answer (score 1):

As reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125947/what-is-the-data-type-for-unix-timestamp-mysql) If you need to store unix timestamp you will need an integer column.

In migration file you can define your column as

```
$table->integer('trx_timestamp');
```

If you need the formatted date you can take benefit from [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators) and define an accessor in your model as

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get formatted trx_timestamp.
     *
     * @param  int $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTrxTimestampAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value)->toDateTimeString();
    }
}
```